# How to set default boolean values in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, boolean

Setting default optional values in JavaScript is usually done via the `||` character

```
var Car = function(color) {
  this.color = color || 'blue';
};

var myCar = new Car();
console.log(myCar.color); // 'blue'

var myOtherCar = new Car('yellow');
console.log(myOtherCar.color); // 'yellow'
```

That works because `color` is `undefined` and `undefined || String` is always the `String`. Of course that also works the other way around `String || undefined` is `String`. When two `Strings` are present the first one wins `'this' || 'that'` is `'this'`. It does NOT work the other way around as `'that' || 'this'` is `'that'`.

The question is: How can I achieve the same with boolean values?

Take the following example

```
var Car = function(hasWheels) {
  this.hasWheels = hasWheels || true;
}

var myCar = new Car();
console.log(myCar.hasWheels); // true

var myOtherCar = new Car(false)
console.log(myOtherCar.hasWheels); // ALSO true !!!!!!
```

For `myCar` it works because `undefined || true` is `true` but as you can see it does NOT work for `myOtherCar` because `false || true` is `true`. Changing the order doesn't help as `true || false` is still `true`.

Therefore, am I missing something here or is the following the only way to set the default value?

```
this.hasWheels = (hasWheels === false) ? false: true
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 142, accepted):

You can do this:

```
this.hasWheels = hasWheels !== false;
```

That gets you a `true` value except when `hasWheels` is explicitly `false`. (Other falsy values, including `null` and `undefined`, will result in `true`, which I think is what you want.)

Comment: @zeMirco: So you're actually asking for all falsey values except for `false` to be considered `true`? If so, I would wonder why you'd want to use `||` in the first place. Clearly an explicit test for `false` would be the simplest solution.

Comment: @thesystem - He didn't want to use `||`; it was just carry-over from using `||` for non-boolean values. The question was posted, I think, because `||` was _not_ doing what was needed.

Comment: If that's the case, then maybe you can also work it out using `^=`.

Comment: @minopret - How would you do that?

Comment: JavaScript is all weird about truthy and falsy things and at this moment I'm too lazy to get together what I'd need in order to investigate what JavaScript actually does, but in a strongly typed language where bitwise operators work on booleans, we have that `x = (x != false)` means just the same as `x ^= false`.

Comment: @minopret - Yes, that weirdness is at the core of the difference between `!=` and `!==`. Unfortunately, JS doesn't have a `^==` operator. (Incidentally, in Java--a strongly typed language--it's not true that "bitwise operators work on booleans". For instance, there are two `^` operators: a bitwise operator that works on integer values and a logical operator that works on booleans. They have different semantics. The story is different in a less-stongly typed language like C that doesn't really distinguish between boolean and int values.)

Comment: That's a cool trick, in my case I wanted undefined arguments to be defaulted to `false`, so I used `this.hasWheels = hasWheels === true`.

Comment: Just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 6):

How about:

```
this.hasWheels = (typeof hasWheels !== 'undefined') ? hasWheels : true;
```

Your other option is:

```
this.hasWheels = arguments.length > 0 ? hasWheels : true;
```

Comment: This does the job well, although I'd suggest using `? !!hasWheels` instead of `? hasWheels` to guarantee that either `true` or `false` (and nothing else) is assigned to `this.hasWheels`.

Answer (score 5):

There are variations to be noted of from posted answers.

```
var Var = function( value ) {
    this.value0 = value !== false;
    this.value1 = value !== false && value !== 'false';
    this.value2 = arguments.length <= 0 ? true : arguments[0];
    this.value3 = arguments[0] === undefined ? true : arguments[0];
    this.value4 = arguments.length <= 0 || arguments[0] === undefined ? true : arguments[0];
};

                     value0   value1   value2        value3         value4
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Var("")              true     true     true          true           true
Var("''")            true     true     ''            ''             ''
Var("0")             true     true     0             0              0
Var("'0'")           true     true     '0'           '0'            '0'
Var("NaN")           true     true     NaN           NaN            NaN
Var("'NaN'")         true     true     'NaN'         'NaN'          'NaN'
Var("null")          true     true     null          null           null
Var("'null'")        true     true     'null'        'null'         'null'
Var("undefined")     true     true     undefined     true           true
Var("'undefined'")   true     true     'undefined'   'undefined'    'undefined'
Var("true")          true     true     true          true           true
Var("'true'")        true     true     'true'        'true'         'true'
Var("false")         false    false    false         false          false
Var("'false'")       true     false    'false'       'false'        'false'
```

- `value1` is made especially from `value0` for string 'false' if one needs it to be boolean false. I found this relaxation useful occationally.
- `value2` and `value3` are modifications of original posted answers for consistency, without changed results.
- `value4` is how Babel compiles for default parameters.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [Default function parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) feature in ECMA6. Today, ECMA6 is still not fully supported in the browser but you can use [babel](https://babeljs.io/) and start using the new features right away.

So, the original example will become as simple as:

```
// specify default value for the hasWheels parameter
var Car = function(hasWheels = true) {
  this.hasWheels = hasWheels;
}

var myCar = new Car();
console.log(myCar.hasWheels); // true

var myOtherCar = new Car(false)
console.log(myOtherCar.hasWheels); // false
```

Comment: but if someone pass in falsy value (i.e empty string) `this.hasWheels` will be assigned that empty string instead of a boolean value. probably want to add `hasWheels = (typeof hasWheels === 'boolean') ? hasWheels : true;`

Answer (score 1):

Without much confusion you can do like this to get a default true.

`this.hasWheels=typeof hasWheels === 'boolean'?hasWheels:true`

To get a default false

`this.hasWheels=typeof hasWheels === 'boolean'?false`