# JavaScript Evaluation Shorthand issue

Tags: javascript, boolean

Possibly very simple but I'm not sure how to correctly write the following evaluation and assignment, where I'm trying to assign configuration values to a widget and set a fallback default value if the config isn't set. If it's not possible in the way I'm attempting, I can fall back to an if/else before setting the value. Grateful for any pointers.

```
console.log(config);

    // Outputs
    {autoplay: false}

    $(el).slick({
        // Sets autoplay to true instead of false, as it evaluates it as not null (I think)
        autoplay: config.autoplay || true,
        // If i set it this way, it works with the correct value as not being evaluated, but then i have no fallback value
        //autoplay: config.autoplay
    });
```

Comment: If `config.autoplay ?? true` isn’t an option, try `(config.hasOwnProperty("autoplay") ? config.autoplay : true)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set default boolean values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15464169/how-to-set-default-boolean-values-in-javascript) — among the first Google results for “js default boolean”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(el).slick({
  autoplay: config.autoplay != null ? config.autoplay : true
});
```

This will check if the value is neither `null` nor `undefined`.

Since the autoplay is false, `false || true` will always result in true.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this if you just want a default value(s).

```js
let config
const defaults = {autoplay:true}

config = {}
console.log({...defaults,...config})

config = {autoplay:true}
console.log({...defaults,...config})

config = {autoplay:false}
console.log({...defaults,...config})

//inlined
config = {}
console.log({autoplay:"default",...config})

//multiple
config = {arg2:"replaced",arg10:"extended"}
console.log({arg1:1, arg2:2, arg3:3,...config})
```